# Memory leak in code snippet

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm trying to dust off my C++.  I knocked together a simple program to find the Fibonacci sequence with memoization.  There's a memory leak, and I can't seem to figure out why. The leak is reported in Fibonacci::setToFind.

Sorry for the long code chunk, but I couldn't figure out how to make a more minimal reproducible example.

```
#include <iostream>

class Fibonacci
{
public:
    int m_valuefound;
    int m_tofind;
    long int *m_memo;

    int findValue(int value){
        if (m_memo[value] == 0) {
            if (value == 0 || value == 1) {
                m_memo[value] = 1;
            } else {
                m_memo[value] = findValue(value-1) + findValue(value-2);
            }
        }
        return m_memo[value];
    }

    void setToFind(int value){
        m_tofind = value;
        m_memo = new long int[value];

        std::fill_n(m_memo,value,0);
    }

    void solve(){

        int value = m_tofind;
        int result = findValue(value);

        std::cout<< "Value is: " << result << std::endl;
    }

    ~Fibonacci(){};


};

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Enter integer values until you'd like to quit.  Enter 0 to quit:";

    int user_ind=0;

    // for testing non-interactivly
    while(true){
    for (user_ind=1; user_ind<45; user_ind++) {
        Fibonacci *test = new Fibonacci;
        test->setToFind(user_ind);
        test->solve();
            delete test;
    }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a `delete [] m_memo` anywhere in the code.

Comment: protip: Don't use pointers. If m_memo was a vector or deque and you wrote `Fibonacci test` instead of have test as a pointer you'd never have a chance of leaking

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Nitpicking, but I think that should be `delete [] m_memo`.

Comment: Quick dust-off: Use `vector`, avoid `new` (you don't need it in the loop). Don't provide untruthful instructions.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: More reason why i suggest deque/vector

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thank you for catching that

Comment: @molbdnilo: I never heard of "untruthful instructions". Google doesn't seem to tell me. What is it?

Comment: you could use valgrind to identify memory leaks for small enough programs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never delete `m_memo` in the destructor of `Fibonacci`.

Since you're allocating m_memo as an array, you should delete with `delete[] m_memo`

Comment: When I add the delete statement, I get garbage back for the sequence values on the second run (and the rest) of the while loop.

Comment: What sequence values? You mean the output value you're getting in `solve()` is garbage?

Comment: A sequence of values I just got was:
Value is: 2
Value is: 2
Value is: 21
Value is: 2
Value is: 2584
Value is: 2
Value is: 2178309
Value is: 2

Comment: You're allocating m_memo as an array of length `value`. And then you `return m_memo[value]` which is out of bounds. Try allocating m_memo with length `value+1`. Again, like others have suggested in the comments, the use of a std::vector would have been a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

Here is working code with a non-copyable `Fibonacci` class. Why don't
you allocate the memory in the constructor. Use RAII wherever possible
and remember The Rule of Five. Avoid all of this in the first place by
using `std::vector`.

```
#include <iostream>

class Fibonacci
{
public:
    int m_valuefound;
    int m_tofind;
    long int *m_memo;

    int findValue(int value){
        if (m_memo[value] == 0) {
            if (value == 0 || value == 1) {
                m_memo[value] = 1;
            } else {
                m_memo[value] = findValue(value-1) + findValue(value-2);
            }
        }
        return m_memo[value];
    }

    void setToFind(int value){
        m_tofind = value;
        m_memo = new long int[value];

        std::fill_n(m_memo,value,0);
    }

    void solve(){

        int value = m_tofind;
        int result = findValue(value);

        std::cout<< "Value is: " << result << std::endl;
    }

  // why don't you allocate in the constructor?
  Fibonacci() : m_valuefound(0), m_tofind(0), m_memo(nullptr) {}

  ~Fibonacci() {
    delete[] m_memo;
  };
  // make the class non-copyable
  Fibonacci(const Fibonacci&) = delete;
  const Fibonacci& operator=(const Fibonacci&) = delete;
  /*
    C++03 non-copyable emulation
private:
  Fibonacci(const Fibonacci&);
  const Fibonacci& operator=(const Fibonacci&);
  */
};
```

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Already fixed. Realized it while hitting post.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating `m_memo` in `setToFind`:

```
m_memo = new long int[value];
```

but your `destructor` does not have a `delete [] m_memo`. You should initialize `m_memo` in your `constructor` and make you class non-copyable by disabling your `copy constructor` and `assignment operator` using `delete` if using C++11:

```
Fibonacci(const Fibonacci&) = delete;
const Fibonacci& operator=(const Fibonacci&) = delete;
```

Otherwise you can make them private. If you used a container such as `std::vector` your life would be much simpler.

Comment: Even if he has a destructor, he is still not initializing the pointer and he still needs to delete the copy constructor and assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use more the STL algorithms. Here's a code snippet with a rather not optimized functor but you can get the idea of the power of the STL:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Fibonacci
{
public:
    Fibonacci();
    ~Fibonacci() {}

    int operator()();
private:
    int n0_;
    int n1_;
    int n_;
};

Fibonacci::Fibonacci():n0_(0),n1_(1),n_(0)
{
}

int Fibonacci::operator()()
{
    if(n_ > 1)
        return (++n0_) + (++n1_);
    else
        return ++n_;
}

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Fibonacci func;
    vector<int> v;

    //generate 100 elements
    generate_n(v.begin(),100,func);

    //printing the values using a lambda expression
    for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),[](const int val){cout << val << endl;});

    return 0;
}
```

You can then apply the finding algorithm you want on the vector using `find_if` and defining your own functor.